# Lazy load images from dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I have an HTML with bunch of images loaded into a div using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<div><img /><img /><img /></div"}} />
```

What I am trying to do is lazy loading the images for performance. I tried few packages such as [react-lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload) but it did not seem lazy loading the images this way. It did work if I pull the HTML string into React component.

How's lazy loading work with images loaded from `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? And how can I lazy load the images?

Comment: Why do you need dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Comment: Simply because the content is generated by users and stored in DB as string

Comment: It is may not possible to achieve it https://github.com/jasonslyvia/react-lazyload/issues/178

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple (and "safe") lazy load solution and not have to use other people's packages/code, try using the `IntersectionObserver` API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

I wrote a Medium article on how to use it to lazy load images in a React component (implementation is essentially the same with vanilla JS).

https://medium.com/@parkjoon94/lazy-loading-images-intersectionobserver-8c5bff730920

You only really need this part of the code (snippet from above article):

```
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const { isIntersecting } = entry;
      if (isIntersecting) {
        this.element.src = this.props.src;
        this.observer = this.observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }, {}
);
```